# how to run some logic before gossiping the block as author?

Tags: substrate-node-template, block-production

In substrate-node-template, are there any available ways to execute a task or provide a callback to be executed just before the block gets gossiped to other validators, right after it has produced the block?

Comment: First you say before it gets gossiped and then before it gets produced. These are different stages. Could you also give more examples on what you want to do with this callback?

Comment: @bkchr oh sorry i meant right after i produce the block which is supposedly exactly before gossiping, but yeah just before gossiping is what i meant, i want to put a value(a bunch of signatures `Vec<Vec<u8>>` in the [dht](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_network/trait.NetworkDHTProvider.html#tymethod.put_value), (i raised some concerns about the dht [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/how-is-the-networkservice-dht-protected-from-dos-attacks-from-a-malicious-valida)

Comment: What kind of extra information?

Comment: @bkchr i want to add the author multiaddr, so just a string

Comment: You could use authority discovery to lookup the multiaddr of the validator?

Comment: @bkchr how? it just returns a Vec<AuthorityId> which are just keys?

Comment: @bkchr forget about modifying the block, what about the question of how to execute a task before the block gets gossiped?

Comment: Left an answer to execute a task before gossiping it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some work before announcing a block to the network, you can do it the following way. [You will need to change this code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8548a97f9272c7ca43ac7c091d81e6b9cc8b69e2/bin/node-template/node/src/service.rs#L173-L182) to something like this:

```rust
   // Don't let the internals announce the block automatically
   config.announce_block = false;
 
   // Start the network etc.
   let (network, system_rpc_tx, tx_handler_controller, network_starter, sync_service) =
        sc_service::build_network(sc_service::BuildNetworkParams {
            config: &config,
            client: client.clone(),
            transaction_pool: transaction_pool.clone(),
            spawn_handle: task_manager.spawn_handle(),
            import_queue,
            block_announce_validator_builder: None,
            warp_sync_params: Some(WarpSyncParams::WithProvider(warp_sync)),
        })?;
    
    let block_import = client.import_notification_stream();
    let custom_block_announce = async move {
        while let Some(import) = block_import.next().await {
            // If the local node produced the block
            if import.origin == BlockOrigin::Own {
                // Insert your special logic here
            }

            // Announce the block to the network
            sync_service.announce_block(import.hash, None);
        }
    };

    task_manager.spawn_handle().spawn(
        "custom-block-announce",
        None,
        custom_block_announce.boxed(),
    );
```